# Spring tool suite vs intellij running a spring boot project

Tags: eclipse, spring, intellij-idea

I was using eclipse - sts , to launch my spring boot projects with option "run as -> spring boot app" and it is working fine , now I decided to switch into intellij IDE, but I'm not able to run my projects anymore, when I try to run my class with Springboot.run , I'm getting

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

[INFO ] 2016-10-11 11:22:54.170 [main] RestApplication - Starting RestApplication on Mateusz-PC with PID 8304 (C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\RESTService\target\classes started by Mateusz in C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\RESTService)
[INFO ] 2016-10-11 11:22:54.214 [main] RestApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[INFO ] 2016-10-11 11:22:54.347 [main] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@209da20d: startup date [Tue Oct 11 11:22:54 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO ] 2016-10-11 11:22:54.375 [background-preinit] Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
[WARN ] 2016-10-11 11:22:54.798 [main] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [pl.kaczynski.RestApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport
[ERROR] 2016-10-11 11:22:54.907 [main] SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [pl.kaczynski.RestApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:286) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at pl.kaczynski.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:11) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more
```

so folks, how should I do this in IntelliJ ??

Comment: The main reason is: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext` Looks like you miss the servlet-api.jar in your classpath

Comment: the stckstrace is shit in this case I suppose , because from STS the same project goes well, or maybe sts adds this jar and intellij doesnt?

Comment: possible. I do not know intellij in detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the Run Configuration. Run -> Edit Configurations and add new configuration. Choose Spring boot and specify the main class and it should do it.